# ListView error: "Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap"

Tags: java, c#, android, listview, xamarin.forms

I'm using FFImageLoading for developing a Xamarin.Forms apps on iOS and Android. On iOS it works fine. But on Android, it always crashes after a while.

The app uses a simple ListView with "CachedImage" elements in each cell.

My app crashes with this error: "Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap"

I use FFImageLoading in a simple Listview with a custom Cell.

This is the crash log:

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@f41b99a
>     ...
>     at java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@f41b99a
>     at at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1270)
>     at at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1404)
>     at at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:544)
>     at at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1244)
>     at at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16178)
>     at at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
>     at at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
>     at at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
>     at at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
>     at at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
>     ... (cut)

My XAML main Page:

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns:cells="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="MyApp.SamplePage"
    Title="SamplePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView
            x:Name="MediaItemsListView"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            SeparatorVisibility="None"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            Margin="15,0,0,0"
            RowHeight="255">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <cells:CellEvento />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This is the main Page codebehind:

```
public partial class SamplePage : ContentPage
    {
        public SamplePage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            MediaItemsListView.ItemsSource = DataProvider.GetMediaItems ();
        }


    }
```

This is the custom Cell XAML:

```
<ViewCell x:Class="MyApp.CellEvento"
                   xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                   xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
               xmlns:fftransformations="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Transformations;assembly=FFImageLoading.Transformations"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                   xmlns:MyApp="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp">

   <AbsoluteLayout WidthRequest="344"
                    HeightRequest="244"
                    BackgroundColor="White" >

<ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="ImageView"
                                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,48,144,152"
                                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="None"
                                    DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                    LoadingPlaceholder="PlaceholderEventBadgePhotoGrayS.png" />

<ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="UserThumbnailView"
                                    WidthRequest="24"
                                    HeightRequest="24"
                                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="298,211,24,24"
                                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="None"
                                    DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                                    LoadingPlaceholder="PlaceholderEventBadgePhotoGrayS.png">
                      <ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                                <fftransformations:CircleTransformation />
                     </ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

</AbsoluteLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

This is the custom cell codebehind:

```
public partial class CellEvento : ViewCell
    {

            public CellEvento ()
            {
                InitializeComponent ();
            }

        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged ()
        {
                        base.OnBindingContextChanged ();
            var mediaItem = BindingContext as MediaItem;
            if (mediaItem != null)
                {
                    ImageView.Source = mediaItem.ImagePath ?? "";
                    UserThumbnailView.Source = mediaItem.AvatarPath ?? "";
                }
        }
    }
```

This is the data provider class:

```
public static class DataProvider
{
  public static ObservableCollection<MediaItem> GetMediaItems ()
     {
ObservableCollection<MediaItem> items = new ObservableCollection<MediaItem> ();
int counter = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < 20; index++)  {
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var item = new MediaItem (
          "Image n." + counter,
          GetRandomImageUrlFlickr (288, 304),
          GetRandomAvatarPhotoUrlFlickr (120, 120),
          counter);
    items.Add (item);
    counter++;
                }
            }
    return items;
         }

        public static string GetRandomImageUrlFlickr (int width, int height)
        {
            return string.Format ("http://loremflickr.com/{1}/{2}/nature?filename={0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid ().ToString ("N"), width, height);
        }

        public static string GetRandomAvatarPhotoUrlFlickr (int width, int height)
        {
            return string.Format ("http://loremflickr.com/{1}/{2}/girl,face/all?filename={0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid ().ToString ("N"), width, height);
        }
}
```

And this is the mediaitem class:

```
public class MediaItem
    {
                public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string AvatarPath {get; set; }

        public MediaItem (string Name, string imagePath, string string avatarPath, int counter)
        {
            this.ImagePath = imagePath;
            this.AvatarPath = avatarPath;
            this.Name = counter.ToString ();
            this.Index = counter;
        }

        public override string ToString ()
        {
            return string.Format ("[MediaItem: Name={0}]", Name);
        }


    }
```

It is a pretty basic setup of a Xamarin.Forms app. The code is almost all in the shared part of the App. As I said the app works fine on iOS. But on Android it crashes.

The Droid project in my Xamarin Studio IDE was pretty basic. I just added the placeholder png to the drawable, and added this initialization code to the MainActivity OnCreate method:

```
//FFImage platform specific initialization code for Droid------
            FFImageLoading.Forms.Droid.CachedImageRenderer.Init ();
            var circlee = new FFImageLoading.Transformations.CircleTransformation ();
            var config = new FFImageLoading.Config.Configuration () {
                VerboseLogging = true,
                VerbosePerformanceLogging = true,
                VerboseMemoryCacheLogging = true,
                VerboseLoadingCancelledLogging = true,
                Logger = new CustomLogger (),
                MaxMemoryCacheSize = 10,
            };
            ImageService.Instance.Initialize (config);
            //-----------------------------------
```

And of course I tried to remove the CircleTrasformation, but it makes no difference. After a few seconds of scroll, the app crashes.

The Android emulators I tried are many: official emulator of a Nexus 5 (standard setup, v19), Nexus 5 (with android v23), and Genymotion Nexus 5 (with android v19), and some more. All gives the same result: crash when scrolling after 2-5 seconds.

What is puzzling me is that, differently from other questions with similar errors here on SO, I don't explicitly call any Recycle command. I let the Listview class handle the recycling by itself.
What I'm missing here?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE: I opened the issue on the ffimageload github repo: 
https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/297

Comment: You mean it works fine with the normal image control?

Comment: yes, it works fine with the standard image control.

Comment: Then please file an issue in the github of the project.

Comment: I already did, but I got no answer: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/297